# How to append a Ajax variable obtained from a loop into a <a href='' '/a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone i'm new to Ajax,i'm using ajax to get values from my database in form of an object array from a separate PHP file and displaying them in a table,everything works fine,but i want to create a link and append the ID obtained from the array so that i can send a GET request to another PHP file which will act upon that particular row.

code for the PHP File

```php
<?php
include 'Module/Credentials.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM queries";
$query=  mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query))
{
    array_push($data, $row);
}
echo json_encode($data);
`
Ajax code

javascript
 `   var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var method="GET";
                    var url="getMessages.php";
                    var asynchronous=true;
                    ajax.open(method, url,asynchronous);
                    ajax.send();
                    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                          var data=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                           console.log(data);
                           var html="";
                           for(var b=0;b<data.length;b++){
                               var ID=data[b].ID;
                               var name=data[b].name;
                               var email=data[b].email;
                               var subject=data[b].subject;
                               var message=data[b].message;
                               var link = "management.php?delete=";
                                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                                  $('.link').attr('href', link+ID);
                                });
                            console.log(data.length);
                                 html +="<tr>";
                                 html +="<td>"+"<a class='link' href=''>Delete</a>"+"</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + name + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + email + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + subject + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + message + "</td>";
                                html +="</tr>";
                               

                           }
                           document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += html;
                        } 
                    }`

the ID on the link is not changing its just displaying a single ID=6

Solution

   ` var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var method="GET";
                    var url="getMessages.php";
                    var asynchronous=true;
                    ajax.open(method, url,asynchronous);
                    ajax.send();
                    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                          var data=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                           console.log(data);
                           var html="";
                           for(var b=0;b<data.length;b++){
                               var ID=data[b].ID;
                               var name=data[b].name;
                               var email=data[b].email;
                               var subject=data[b].subject;
                               var message=data[b].message;
                               var link = `management.php?delete=${ID}`;
                                 html +="<tr>";
                                 html +=`<td><a href='${link}'>Delete</a></td>`;
                                 html +="<td>" + name + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + email + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + subject + "</td>";
                                 html +="<td>" + message + "</td>";
                                html +="</tr>";
                               

                           }
                           document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += html;
                           
                        }
                    }`
but i'm getting error messages in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 like
Expected an operand but found error
    `var link== `management.php?delete=${ID}`;`
Expected an operand but found error
    `html +=`<td><a href='${link}'>Delete</a></td>`;`
Expected eof but found error   ` }`
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why don't you use `$.ajax()` instead of the verbose `XMLHttpRequest` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Template Literal like so:

```js
var link = `management.php?delete=${ID}`;
```

And if you want it on the `html`

```js
html +=`<td><a class='link' href='${link}'>Delete</a></td>`;
```

Please note that I'm using the back ticks **`**

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: When i try that im now ending up with ```url/management.php?delete=${ID}``` in the url,if i revert to the previous code im getting ```url/management.php?delete=7``` but when i console.log(ID); im getting three different IDs cause thats what i have

Comment: all i want is to pass the ```ID``` for each row into the ```<a hrer=' '/a>``` so that when i send to the PHP file which delete's the row,the ID is used as a variable in a MYSQL DELETE statement

Comment: And you are definitely using the backticks / grave accent?

Comment: yes iam using the backticks ```url/management.php?delete=7```` yet i have three rows with different ID's

Comment: I see that is very strange, by using the backticks JS should convert the `${...}` to the value of that variable and return the string accordingly. Unfortunately I can't help anymore if I don't see your current code as you last comment just left me more confused

Comment: Thanks its worked now,i'd forgot to remove the  ```$(document).ready(function(){ 
                                 $('.link').attr('href', link);
                                });``` function

Comment: Glad it worked, if that is the case you should leave the questions as is, don't ask more and different questions if you get another error, in such case is best to create a new question. I would not mind if you accept my answer as the correct one if indeed helpd to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Before selecting a HTML element you have to create it. After creation you can manipulate.